Boolean not updating in view but updating in struct
I'm quite new to SwiftUI and I am building an application that breaks down tasks into subtasks using AI, but I'm having issues displaying said Subtasks. The current functionality I want is for the user to be able to tick every subtask that they complete and it persists throughout the application, I am using SwiftData for this. I have the basic UI for the checklist implemented but the isCompleted property just does not want to toggle.
The toggle() function produces the same results but including the mutating function helps me to debug this.
I included debug prints in the code to debug the changes to the variable.
Here is the code for the task and subtask class/struct:
@Model
class BlendedTask: Codable, Identifiable {
    var id = UUID()
    let name: String
    var subtasks: [Subtask]
    
    var task: UserTask {
        return UserTask(id: id, name: name, duration: 3, startTime: nil, priority: .medium, imageURL: "tornado", details: nil, pomodoro: true, pomodoroCounter: 0, blended: true)
    }
    
    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id, name, subtasks
    }
    
    //  Initializers
    
    init(name: String, subtasks: [Subtask]) {
        self.name = name
        self.subtasks = subtasks
    }
    
    init() {
        self.id = UUID()
        self.name = ""
        self.subtasks = []
    }
    
    required init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        name = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .name)
        subtasks = try container.decode([Subtask].self, forKey: .subtasks)
    }
}

// Subtask
struct Subtask: Codable, Identifiable, Hashable{
    var id = UUID()
    let name: String
    var details: [Detail]

    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id, name, details
    }
}
// Subtask details
struct Detail: Codable, Identifiable, Hashable {
    var id = UUID()
    var description: String
    var isCompleted: Bool
    
    init(description: String) {
        self.description = description
        self.isCompleted = false
    }
    
    mutating func toggleCompleted() {
        print("-struct OLD: \(self.isCompleted)")
        self.isCompleted.toggle()
        print("-struct NEW: \(self.isCompleted)")
        print("toggled for detail: \(self.description)")
    }
}

And here is the implementation in the view to show the details:
struct BlendedTaskDetailView: View {
    @Environment(\.dismiss) private var dismiss

    @State private var isAnimated = false
    @Bindable var blendedTask: BlendedTask
    
    var body: some View {
        
        ZStack {
            Color.BG.ignoresSafeArea()
            VStack {
                Text("Task: " + blendedTask.name)
                    //modifiers
                
                List {
                    ForEach(Array($blendedTask.subtasks.enumerated()), id: \.1.id) { index, $subtask  in
                        SubtaskCell(subtask: $subtask, taskNo: index + 1)
                    }
                    .listRowBackground(Color.faPurple)
                }
                // Modifiers
            }
            .padding(.top, 30)
            
        }
    }
}

struct SubtaskCell: View {
    @Binding var subtask: Subtask
    let taskNo: Int
    
    @State private var isAnimated = false
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .center) {
            Text("Task \(taskNo): \(subtask.name)")
                // modifiers
            
            ForEach(subtask.details.indices, id: \.self) { j in
                DetailRow(detail: $subtask.details[j])
            }
            
        }
        //modifiers
    }
}

struct DetailRow: View {
    @Binding var detail: Detail
    @State private var isAnimated = false
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                Text(detail.description)
            }
            Spacer()
            
            Button(action: {
                withAnimation {
                    print("-view OLD: \(detail.isCompleted)")
                    detail.toggleCompleted()
                    print("-view NEW: \(detail.isCompleted)")
                }
            }, label: {
                Image(systemName: detail.isCompleted ? "checkmark.circle.fill" : "circle")
                    .contentTransition(.symbolEffect(.replace))
                
            })
            .frame(width: 35, height: 35)
            .foregroundStyle(detail.isCompleted ? .green : .white)
            
        }
       //modifiers
    }
}

Here is what the UI looks like:

This is what is printed when a button is pressed:


State should always be private you are just making a copy of the value

Does it help to change ForEach(subtask.details.indices, id: .self) { j in
DetailRow(detail: $subtask.details[j])
}
To
ForEach(subtask.details) { detail in
DetailRow(detail: $detail)
}

I tried both of these and the behavior still remains the same.
@loremipsum, I made the state private and used an initializer instead, is that the best way to go about it?

If you want to get updates use “let”  or Binding/Bindable. State is a source of truth it just makes copies.

I was originally using bindable but i changed it to state to see if that would fix the issue, forgot to change it back. Still the same issue, I'll edit the post as well

You should simplify your code to an MRE. If you want someone to debug.

With SwiftData Identifiable shouldn't be on your @model class because objects already have identity (their pointer). And I think it would be best if you changed  your related struct entities to be model classes too, that way you can @Query for them.

Might be a dumb question as I this is my first time using SwiftData, why create separate models for the structs when I can Use @Query on the BlendedTask class and get the properties from the structs from there?

After a few days I found the problem to my issue. I used an SQLite browser to look at what was going on in the SwiftData database, and my structs were being stored as JSON objects, so every change I made to them were being coded into JSON and stored in SwiftData. But because I wasn't encoding isCompleted it was not being saved.
I converted subtask and detail into models and created dummy Structs for decoding. Here is my solution below.
These are the models
@Model class BlendedTask {
    var id = UUID()
    var name: String
    @Relationship(deleteRule: .cascade, inverse: \Subtask.blendedTask)
    var subtasks = [Subtask]()
    
    init(from dummyTask: DummyTask) {
        self.name = dummyTask.name
        self.subtasks = []
    }
    
    func toTask() -> UserTask {
        return UserTask(id: id, name: name, duration: 3, priority: .medium, pomodoro: true, pomodoroCounter: 0, blended: true)
    }
    
    
    init(name: String, subtasks: [Subtask]) {
        self.name = name
        self.subtasks = subtasks
    }
    
}

@Model class Subtask {
    var name: String
    @Relationship(deleteRule: .cascade, inverse: \Detail.subtask)
    var details = [Detail]()
    var blendedTask: BlendedTask?
    
    init(name: String, details: [Detail]) {
        self.name = name
        self.details = details
    }
    
    init(from dummySubtask: DummySubtask) {
        self.name = dummySubtask.name
        self.details = []
    }
    
}

@Model class Detail {
    var desc: String
    var isCompleted: Bool
    var subtask: Subtask?
    
    init(desc: String, isCompleted: Bool) {
        self.desc = desc
        self.isCompleted = isCompleted
    }
    
    init(from dummyDetail: DummyDetail) {
        self.desc = dummyDetail.desc
        self.isCompleted = dummyDetail.isCompleted
    }
}

My application creates a BlendedTask, with it's subtasks and details already populated, and that causes issues with SwiftData relationships so I made codable structs as a temporary store of the data then I initialise the objects in the database one by one to establish the relationships properly. Here's what I did
struct DummyTask: Codable {
    var name: String
    var subtasks = [DummySubtask]()
    
    init(name: String, subtasks: [DummySubtask]) { standard init }
    
    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey { coding keys }
    
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws { decoding methods }
    
    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws { encoding methods }

    init(_ json: String, using encoding: String.Encoding = .utf8) throws { init from json string }

struct DummySubtask: Codable {
    var name: String
    var details = [DummyDetail]()
    
    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey { coding keys }
    
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws { decoding methods }
    
    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws { encoding methods }
}

struct DummyDetail: Codable {
    var desc: String
    var isCompleted: Bool
    
    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey { coding keys }
    
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws { decoding methods }
    
    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws { encoding methods }
}

And finally this is how I initialised the models from JSON String
func decodeBlendedTask(from JSONString: String, modelContext: ModelContext) throws -> BlendedTask {
    let dummyTask = try DummyTask.init(JSONString)
    let blendedTask = BlendedTask(from: dummyTask)
    modelContext.insert(blendedTask)
    var subtasks = [Subtask]()
    
    
    for subtask in dummyTask.subtasks.reversed() {
        var details = [Detail]()
        
        let newSubtask = Subtask(from: subtask)
        modelContext.insert(newSubtask)
        //Assign the relationship after inserting into context
        newSubtask.blendedTask = blendedTask
        
        for detail in subtask.details.reversed() {
            let newDetail = Detail(from: detail)
            modelContext.insert(newDetail)
            //Assign the relationship after inserting into context
            newDetail.subtask = newSubtask
            details.append(newDetail)
        }
        newSubtask.details = details
        subtasks.append(newSubtask)
    }
    
    blendedTask.subtasks = subtasks
    
    return blendedTask
}

This way there is way less nesting and the Bool is stored directly in the model, making modifying it much simpler.
